# Visual Studio Code disable Getting Started

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-code

I have a question regarding Visual Studio Code deployment.
Visual Studio Code opens IE window to show Documentation for Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs?start=true) at first launch.
Is it possible to disable this? 
I didn't find the proper setting. It seems that the Documentation window is not shown if the file %APPDATA%\Roaming\Code\Local Storage\file__0.localstorage exist. But I'm not sure if the same file can be used to suppress the IE window on different PCs and for different users.

Answer (score 2):

you can go to File > Preferences > Settings, search "Startup Editor" in "Search Settings" and choose "None" from the drop-down menu.